# BeatifulSoup find,select method returns None

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

> I am trying to get all the divs present inside div having id ='qx-row-98352'  , all these three return me an empty list which I am not able to call find_all() on it.

```
      # spandv = soup.find(id="qx-row-98352")
    
      # spandv = soup.find("div",{"id": "qx-row-98352"})
    
      # spandv = soup.select('#qx-row-98352')
```

myCode

```
    source = urllib.request.urlopen("https://etisalat.af/index.php/about-us/doing-business-with-us/tenders").read()
    soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(source,'lxml')


    spandv = soup.find(id="qx-row-98352")
    print(spandv)  // returns  []

  # spandv = soup.find("div",{"id": "qx-row-98352"})

  # spandv = soup.select('#qx-row-98352')

    cont_divs = spandv.find_all('div')  // Line 1 generates error

    print(cont_divs)
```

error I am getting at line 1 is :

**cont_divs = spandv.find_all('div')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all'**

could any one help me with the issue.
thanks in advance.
[image]

Comment: What is your expected result?

Comment: i edited the post, is it clear now?

Comment: you may please check the url used in the request

Comment: Do you want to have all the html content inside the desired div printed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get correct HTML response from the server, you have to specift `User-Agent` HTTP header, and `antibot` cookie. (Here I copied the cookie from browser, maybe you need to do the same):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://etisalat.af/index.php/about-us/doing-business-with-us/tenders'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:79.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/79.0'}
cookies = {'antibot': "0ffb515c2bb41440c468d6fee1453ca8"}

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url, headers=headers, cookies=cookies).content, 'html.parser')

for a in soup.select('#qx-row-98352 a.qx-btn'):
    print(a['href'])
```

Prints:

```
https://www.etisalat.af/images/pdf_files/RFQ for Supply of Fiber spare parts.xls
https://www.etisalat.af/images/pdf_files/RFP for Digital Services.pdf
https://www.etisalat.af/images/pdf_files/RFP for Copiers  Printers Service and Supply of Spare Parts.pdf
https://www.etisalat.af/images/pdf_files/RFQ for Supply of ACB Spare parts_ (2).xls
https://www.etisalat.af/images/pdf_files/RFQ for m-Hawala Subscription Application Form.pdf
https://www.etisalat.af/images/pdf_files/RFQ for Supply of DG Spare parts.xls
https://www.etisalat.af/images/pdf_files/RFQ for Supply of ACB Spare parts_ (2).xls
https://www.etisalat.af/images/pdf_files/RFQ for Supply of Fiber spare parts.xls
https://www.etisalat.af/images/pdf_files/RFP for Microsoft Lync 2010 Upgarde to Microsoft Teams.pdf
https://www.etisalat.af/images/pdf_files/RFQ for Supply of ZTE BSS  burnt site recovery spare parts.xls
https://www.etisalat.af/images/pdf_files/RFQ for Fire Alarm System in EA Guest House-2020.pdf
https://www.etisalat.af/images/pdf_files/Notice for  Auction of Used Oil-Etisalat Afghanistan August- 2020.pdf
https://www.etisalat.af/images/pdf_files/RFP for Microsoft Lync 2010 Upgarde to Microsoft Teams Telephony.pdf
https://www.etisalat.af/images/pdf_files/RFQ for Supply of ZTE DWDM Spare parts_.xls
https://www.etisalat.af/images/pdf_files/RFQ for m-Hawala Receipt.pdf
https://www.etisalat.af/images/pdf_files/RFQ for Supply of Huawei DWDM Spare parts_.xls
https://www.etisalat.af/images/pdf_files/RFQ for Supply and installation of Air condition.xls
https://www.etisalat.af/images/pdf_files/RFQ for Supply of ACB Spare parts_.xls
https://www.etisalat.af/images/pdf_files/RFQ for Renewal of Web Hosting Services - 12-08-20.pdf
https://www.etisalat.af/images/pdf_files/RFP for Air System-(ACs) Maintenance-on-Call.pdf
https://www.etisalat.af/images/pdf_files/RFQ for supply of 5 and 10 Years Loyalty Award.pdf
https://www.etisalat.af/images/pdf_files/RFQ for supply of security camera.pdf
```

Comment: thank you Andrej, I appreciate your help. i copied header and cookies from my browser in my computer and it works fine. but what about if I save it to a server will it work in there if I keep the same header and cookies inside the file. if it will not work what is my solution.?

Comment: @TalibDaryabi You can try it. Other solution is to use `selenium` - this uses real web browser, but you need to have it installed on the server.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the web page is dynamically loaded, you could use something like selenium for that:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request

from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.firefox import GeckoDriverManager

driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=GeckoDriverManager().install())
driver.get('https://etisalat.af/index.php/about-us/doing-business-with-us/tenders')

content = driver.page_source    
soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'lxml')

desired_div = soup.find('div',attrs={"id":"qx-row-98352"})
print(desired_div)
```

OUTPUT:

```
<div class="qx-row" id="qx-row-98352">
<div class="qx-column qx-col-lg-6 qx-col-md-6 qx-col-sm-12 qx-col-xs-12" id="qx-column-32353">
<div class="qx-element qx-element-button" id="qx-button-72229">
<a class="qx-btn qx-btn-default qx-hidden-lg qx-hidden-md qx-hidden-sm qx-hidden-xs qx-btn-block" href="https://www.etisalat.af/images/pdf_files/RFQ for Supply of Fiber spare parts.xls">
<i class="fa fa-download"></i>
        RFQ for Supply of Fiber spare parts      </a>
</div>
<!-- qx-element-button -->
<div class="qx-element qx-element-button" id="qx-button-67122">
<a class="qx-btn qx-btn-default qx-hidden-lg qx-hidden-md qx-hidden-sm qx-hidden-xs qx-btn-block" href="https://www.etisalat.af/images/pdf_files/RFP for Digital Services.pdf">
<i class="fa fa-download"></i>
        RFP for Digital Services      </a>
</div>
<!-- qx-element-button -->
<div class="qx-element qx-element-button" id="qx-button-6921">
<a class="qx-btn qx-btn-default qx-hidden-lg qx-hidden-md qx-hidden-sm qx-hidden-xs qx-btn-block" href="https://www.etisalat.af/images/pdf_files/RFP for Copiers  Printers Service and Supply of Spare Parts.pdf">
<i class="fa fa-download"></i>
        RFP for Copiers  Printers Service and Supply of Spare Parts      </a>
</div>
<!-- qx-element-button -->
<div class="qx-element qx-element-button" id="qx-button-6125">
<a class="qx-btn qx-btn-default qx-hidden-lg qx-hidden-md qx-hidden-sm qx-hidden-xs qx-btn-block" href="https://www.etisalat.af/images/pdf_files/RFQ for Supply of ACB Spare parts_ (2).xls">
<i class="fa fa-download"></i>
        RFQ for Supply of ACB Spare parts      </a>
</div>
<!-- qx-element-button -->
<div class="qx-element qx-element-button" id="qx-button-627">
<a class="qx-btn qx-btn-default qx-hidden-lg qx-hidden-md qx-hidden-sm qx-hidden-xs qx-btn-block" href="https://www.etisalat.af/images/pdf_files/RFQ for m-Hawala Subscription Application Form.pdf">
<i class="fa fa-download"></i>
        RFQ for m-Hawala Subscription Application Form      </a>
</div>
<!-- qx-element-button -->
<div class="qx-element qx-element-button" id="qx-button-5321">
<a class="qx-btn qx-btn-default qx-hidden-lg qx-hidden-md qx-hidden-sm qx-hidden-xs qx-btn-block" href="https://www.etisalat.af/images/pdf_files/RFQ for Supply of DG Spare parts.xls">
<i class="fa fa-download"></i>
        RFQ for Supply of DG Spare parts      </a>
</div>
<!-- qx-element-button -->
<div class="qx-element qx-element-button" id="qx-button-11150">
<a class="qx-btn qx-btn-default qx-hidden-lg qx-hidden-md qx-hidden-sm qx-hidden-xs qx-btn-block" href="https://www.etisalat.af/images/pdf_files/RFQ for Supply of ACB Spare parts_ (2).xls">
<i class="fa fa-download"></i>
        RFQ for Supply of ACB Spare parts      </a>
</div>
<!-- qx-element-button -->
<div class="qx-element qx-element-button" id="qx-button-39265">
<a class="qx-btn qx-btn-default qx-hidden-lg qx-hidden-md qx-hidden-sm qx-hidden-xs qx-btn-block" href="https://www.etisalat.af/images/pdf_files/RFQ for Supply of Fiber spare parts.xls">
<i class="fa fa-download"></i>
        RFQ for Supply of Fiber spare parts      </a>
</div>
<!-- qx-element-button -->
<div class="qx-element qx-element-button" id="qx-button-2240">
<a class="qx-btn qx-btn-default qx-hidden-lg qx-hidden-md qx-hidden-sm qx-hidden-xs qx-btn-block" href="https://www.etisalat.af/images/pdf_files/RFP for Microsoft Lync 2010 Upgarde to Microsoft Teams.pdf">
<i class="fa fa-download"></i>
        RFP for Microsoft Lync 2010 Upgarde to Microsoft Teams      </a>
</div>
<!-- qx-element-button -->
<div class="qx-element qx-element-button" id="qx-button-90155">
<a class="qx-btn qx-btn-default qx-hidden-lg qx-hidden-md qx-hidden-sm qx-hidden-xs qx-btn-block" href="https://www.etisalat.af/images/pdf_files/RFQ for Supply of ZTE BSS  burnt site recovery spare parts.xls">
<i class="fa fa-download"></i>
        RFQ for Supply of ZTE BSS  burnt site recovery spare parts      </a>
</div>
<!-- qx-element-button -->
<div class="qx-element qx-element-button" id="qx-button-33132">
<a class="qx-btn qx-btn-default qx-btn-block" href="https://www.etisalat.af/images/pdf_files/RFQ for Fire Alarm System in EA Guest House-2020.pdf">
<i class="fa fa-download"></i>
        RFQ for Fire Alarm System in EA Guest House      </a>
</div>
<!-- qx-element-button -->
<div class="qx-element qx-element-button" id="qx-button-755">
<a class="qx-btn qx-btn-default qx-btn-block" href="https://www.etisalat.af/images/pdf_files/Notice for  Auction of Used Oil-Etisalat Afghanistan August- 2020.pdf">
<i class="fa fa-download"></i>
        Notice for  Auction of Used Oil-Etisalat Afghanistan      </a>
</div>
<!-- qx-element-button -->
<div class="qx-element qx-element-button" id="qx-button-7637">
<a class="qx-btn qx-btn-default qx-btn-block" href="https://www.etisalat.af/images/pdf_files/RFP for Microsoft Lync 2010 Upgarde to Microsoft Teams Telephony.pdf">
<i class="fa fa-download"></i>
        RFP for Microsoft Lync 2010 Upgarde to Microsoft Teams Telephony      </a>
</div>
<!-- qx-element-button -->
</div>
<!-- qx-col -->
<div class="qx-column qx-col-lg-6 qx-col-md-6 qx-col-sm-12 qx-col-xs-12" id="qx-column-70357">
<div class="qx-element qx-element-button" id="qx-button-918">
<a class="qx-btn qx-btn-default qx-hidden-lg qx-hidden-md qx-hidden-sm qx-hidden-xs qx-btn-block" href="https://www.etisalat.af/images/pdf_files/RFQ for Supply of ZTE DWDM Spare parts_.xls">
<i class="fa fa-download"></i>
        RFQ for Supply of ZTE DWDM Spare parts      </a>
</div>
<!-- qx-element-button -->
<div class="qx-element qx-element-button" id="qx-button-5423">
<a class="qx-btn qx-btn-default qx-hidden-lg qx-hidden-md qx-hidden-sm qx-hidden-xs qx-btn-block" href="https://www.etisalat.af/images/pdf_files/RFQ for m-Hawala Receipt.pdf">
<i class="fa fa-download"></i>
        RFQ for m-Hawala Receipt      </a>
</div>
<!-- qx-element-button -->
<div class="qx-element qx-element-button" id="qx-button-12124">
<a class="qx-btn qx-btn-default qx-hidden-lg qx-hidden-md qx-hidden-sm qx-hidden-xs qx-btn-block" href="https://www.etisalat.af/images/pdf_files/RFQ for Supply of Huawei DWDM Spare parts_.xls">
<i class="fa fa-download"></i>
        RFQ for Supply of Huawei DWDM Spare parts      </a>
</div>
<!-- qx-element-button -->
<div class="qx-element qx-element-button" id="qx-button-3337">
<a class="qx-btn qx-btn-default qx-hidden-lg qx-hidden-md qx-hidden-sm qx-hidden-xs qx-btn-block" href="https://www.etisalat.af/images/pdf_files/RFQ for Supply and installation of Air condition.xls">
<i class="fa fa-download"></i>
        RFQ for Supply and installation of Air condition      </a>
</div>
<!-- qx-element-button -->
<div class="qx-element qx-element-button" id="qx-button-25127">
<a class="qx-btn qx-btn-default qx-hidden-lg qx-hidden-md qx-hidden-sm qx-hidden-xs qx-btn-block" href="https://www.etisalat.af/images/pdf_files/RFQ for Supply of ACB Spare parts_.xls">
<i class="fa fa-download"></i>
        RFQ for Supply of ACB Spare parts      </a>
</div>
<!-- qx-element-button -->
<div class="qx-element qx-element-button" id="qx-button-5241">
<a class="qx-btn qx-btn-default qx-btn-block" href="https://www.etisalat.af/images/pdf_files/RFQ for Renewal of Web Hosting Services - 12-08-20.pdf">
<i class="fa fa-download"></i>
        RFQ for Renewal of Web Hosting Services      </a>
</div>
<!-- qx-element-button -->
<div class="qx-element qx-element-button" id="qx-button-23362">
<a class="qx-btn qx-btn-default qx-btn-block" href="https://www.etisalat.af/images/pdf_files/RFP for Air System-(ACs) Maintenance-on-Call.pdf">
<i class="fa fa-download"></i>
        RFP for Air System-(ACs) Maintenance-on-Call      </a>
</div>
<!-- qx-element-button -->
<div class="qx-element qx-element-button" id="qx-button-30632">
<a class="qx-btn qx-btn-default qx-hidden-lg qx-hidden-md qx-hidden-sm qx-hidden-xs qx-btn-block" href="https://www.etisalat.af/images/pdf_files/RFQ for supply of 5 and 10 Years Loyalty Award.pdf">
<i class="fa fa-download"></i>
        RFQ for supply of 5 and 10 Years Loyalty Award      </a>
</div>
<!-- qx-element-button -->
<div class="qx-element qx-element-button" id="qx-button-59737">
<a class="qx-btn qx-btn-default qx-hidden-lg qx-hidden-md qx-hidden-sm qx-hidden-xs qx-btn-block" href="https://www.etisalat.af/images/pdf_files/RFQ for supply of security camera.pdf">
<i class="fa fa-download"></i>
        RFQ for supply of security camera      </a>
</div>
<!-- qx-element-button -->
<div class="qx-element qx-element-image qx-hidden-lg qx-hidden-md qx-hidden-sm qx-hidden-xs" id="qx-image-92128">
<a class="qx-image--lightbox" href="/images/pdf_files/mHawalareceipt.jpg">
<img class="qx-img qx-img-responsive" src="/images/pdf_files/mHawalareceipt.jpg"/>
</a>
</div>
<!-- qx-element-image --></div>
<!-- qx-col -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `soup.findAll`

```py
soup.findAll("div",{"id": "qx-row-98352"})
```